# How to reflect local database changes to TEST environment database in entityframework database first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4 + EntityFramework **Database First** application. I have made some changes in my local database (added table and columns in couple of tables). After this I updated my `.edmx` file and ran the custom tool. This has updated my models of the table whose schema i have changed. Everything is working fine.

I want to know, How to reflect those local database changes on my Test database?

Comment: Within VS you can compare the two data bases and generate a change script that will bring them on par with each other.

Comment: Yes, as Nkosi says there is a schema compare tool in VS. http://www.techbubbles.com/sql-server/schema-compare-for-sql-server-in-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: You just script out the SQL. It's a manual process. Or use a tool as several people have suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within VS you can compare the two databases and generate a change script that will bring them on par with each other.

In your case you want to do a schema compare.

Tools -> SQL Server -> New Schema Comparison.

You select your local database and then select the test database. it will compare the schema of both and show you the differences. You can select which you want to apply and either apply it directly or generate a change script and execute when you want from SSMS.

[Compare and Synchronize Database Schemas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193250(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio you can export the database script to drop and recreate the tables, indexes, relationships, etc... You can also use Visual Studio to export the SQL script to create all the tables. The other way is to manually add the updated columns. I'm unsure of any other ways to do this in a database first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try SQL Server Data Tools for Visual studio :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx

Very easy and intuitive to use for Schema comparison and generating delta scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at [xSQL Schema Compare](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_schema_compare/?utm_source=pragmatic&utm_medium=articles&utm_campaign=xsql). It's a great tool for comparing and synchronizing database schemas. It should do the trick in your case. Also, this comes bundled with [xSQL Data Compare](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_data_compare/?utm_source=pragmatic&utm_medium=articles&utm_campaign=xsql) which you can use to compare and synchronize the data as well, should the need to do so arise.